# Training a model for Latent-SVM

Tags: matlab, model, svm

GOOD MORNING COLLEAGUES!

I am very into train a new model from my own data set of faces!

I have found no information about this topic, then I hope my information could help people and I can get some answers as well.

I will try to explain the steps I have needed to do to train my own model and later on some questions...

- I have download the Latent code from: http://cs.brown.edu/~pff/latent-release4/
- I have download the PASCAL VOC 2008 code (devkit) from: http://host.robots.ox.ac.uk/pascal/VOC/voc2008/index.html
- I have emulate the structure of files/folders of the VOC PASCAL but in my own data set:

  - **Annotations**. I have created a .xml where I have defined a object, face, (in each image I only have one face). I didn't define difficulties or poses...
  - **JPEGImages** where I have stored all the images
  - **ImageSets** where I have defined three files:

    - *test.txt*, where I wrote the file name of my positive samples
    - *train.txt*, where I wrote the file name of my negative samples
    - *trainval.txt*, where I wrote the file name of my positive samples (exactly the same file than test.txt).
- I have change some things in globals.m and VOCinit.m (to tell the algorithm the path and the location of some files...)

---

Then I run the training with the command: pascal('face', 1);

Following these steps I have achieved that the training run completely and doesn't fail and I get my own model **BUT** I have some doubts...

1. Can you see anything weird in my explanation? Could it work?
2. Must the files test.txt/trainval.txt be equal? Why... What does it mean?
3. Do I have to choose the number of parts I want in the model INSIDE the function?
4. Please, you imagine I have two kind of samples (frontal faces and side faces) and I want to detect both... How can I address this issue? I thought I have to train a model with two components... but How can I tell to the training code which are frontal or side samples?? In the annotations with the label pose?? (I don't think so...) Are there other way to handle this purpose?

**Thank you for your time!!
I hope you can solve my doubts :)**

Comment: Well.... @3yanlis1bos or Pablo Rivas, maybe you could help me.

I gathered these set of images to train TWO models (frontal face and lateral face):
* (300 frontal + 300 lateral) Positive samples --> trainval.txt
* (1000) Negative samples --> train.txt
* (100) Test samples --> test.txt

Due to my images are very statics (very similar between them) I rotated some degrees randomly to create some variability in the training.

Is that correct?

My problem is that when I run my detector the scores for the positive and negative samples are QUITE similar... then I get too much FP and FN...

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

I think `test.txt` should contain samples (images) that will be used to estimate how good the system is after learning the faces. However, `trainval.txt` is used during the learning stage (training) to fine-tune the parameters of the model; it is an essential part of supervised learning.

Also, it is very hard to have one single SVM to classify faces that are both frontal and sideways. Here is my suggestion:

- Train one SVM to detect if the input image is a frontal face or a sideways face. Call this something like `SVM-0`.
- Train another SVM for frontal faces. This SVM will classify all your individuals. Note, however, that SVM is usually a binary classifier, so make sure you choose the right SVM, one that as a multiclass architecture. Call this `SVM-F`.
- Tran a final SVM for sideways faces. Again, use a multiclass SVM. Call it `SVM-S`.

Present the input image to `SVM-0` and if it detects it is a frontal face, present the input again to `SVM-F`; otherwise, give the input to `SVM-S`.

In my experience, you should expect very low performance in `SVM-S`. It is a hard problem to solve. But frontal faces is not a big deal, unless you are working with faces that vary in pose, illumination, and expression (PIE). Face recognition is affected greatly with PIE variations in the images.

I recommend you [this website](http://www.face-rec.org/), it contains very good information and tutorials for starters, with or without experience.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!! :)

Then:
  - **trainval.txt** are the positive samples to train the model
  - **train.txt** are the negatives samples to train the model
  - **test.txt** are other annotated samples (positives and negatives) positive samples to train the model to check how the training was.. right? This part (test.txt) affect to the final model (affect to the training?)?

I am in to detect faces (and their poses) but I don't need to recognise them. My goal is tell if the face of the person is visible (or not) and the pose (frontal / lateral).

**Am I right?**

Comment: Not quite. See, `train.txt`, `trainval.txt`, and `test.txt` should all contain both positive and negative samples. I recommend you to [https://youtu.be/4wGquWG-vGw](watch this video) that explains the concept of training, validation, and testing sets.  If your intention is to 1) detect a face, and 2) detect if it is frontal/lateral, then the problem is simpler than I thought. First, train an SVM to detect a `face` (+ class) or `not a face` (- class). Second, train another SVM that will detect if the face is `frontal` (+ class) or `lateral` (- class). You'll need samples to train both SVMs.